# R Is Concurrent Modify to Large Data.Table or dataframe acceptable?

Tags: r, windows, multithreading, dataframe, data.table

Imagine a 12mm Data.Table.

I want to

1. create a new column and compute a new value using a complex algo using data only from the row.
2. break the 12mm rows into 1mm sections and have 1 cpu thread handle each of the 12x 1mm chunks (its a multi-core, 12 thread CPU).

This means 12 threads will iterate through their section of the data.table, read data from a row, compute a value and store it in a different column in the row.

Note:

- the new column is being created before multi-threading
- each thread is accessing a different part of the data.table by index
- the function is too complex to do another way
- right now the processing is sequentialthrough the data.table, only uses one CPU thread and runs for other 3 hours.

Q: What's a better way to increase "same machine" concurrency with 12mm rows using complex functions?
Q: what's broken with this scenario?

Comment: *"Imagine a 12mm Data.Table."* That's quite thin.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49826865/edit) your question to include a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), including sample data. At the moment your questions are too broad for SO and lacking in specific coding details.

Comment: (1) is likely covered with `apply(dx,1,...)`. (2) might be addressed with `expand.grid` or `outer`. Have you tried anything? (Q1) Add RAM. (Q2) Honestly, I'm not sure, because *everything you've offered is hypothetical.*

Comment: @r2evans It might not be wise to propose using `apply()` with a `data.frame` or `data.table` in general as the dataset will be coerced to `matrix` with *all* columns of the same type. See section 8.2.38 of Patrick Burn's [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: You are correct ... but in a vague comparison to Schrödinger's cat, "data table", "data frame", and similar structures are not necessarily `data.table` and `data.frame` until their true state is realized by actually seeing code/data structures.